# C# Convert Char to KeyValue

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a char, for example 'A'.
How I can get KeyValue after which will write this character ('A')?

Thanks for reading,
Greetings.

PS:
How to obtain the function SendInput large / small letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

static public Key ResolveKey(char charToResolve)
{
    return KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(VkKeyScan(charToResolve));
}
```

Comment: -1 for using copy/paste of a previous answer word for word, without giving credit and without providing a link to the question/answer.